# In general, can we prove that admissible quadratic polynomials must yield at least one prime value?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratics, coprime

By admissible, I'm referring to an integer-valued quadratic function with no common factors, i.e. one that meets the basic requirements to be able to produce primes. To be more specific, a quadratic polynomial $f(x):=ax^2+bx+c$ with $a>0$ where  $x\in\mathbb Z \implies f(x) \in\mathbb Z$, and where there exist $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ with $\gcd(f(m),f(n))=1$ and $ m \neq n$. In short, a quadratic which has no a priori reason to be prime-free.

First, I know the infinitude of quadratic primes is an open question, so I suspect this will be too, but I'll ask anyway. Do we know of any quadratic functions that should be able to produce primes yet they don't seem to? By this, I mean an admissible quadratic as described above but for which computer searches have been unable to find any prime values.

I'm assuming not, in which case my primary question is: have we reached the point yet where we can prove, in general, that an admissible quadratic function as described above must yield at least one prime value? Or is that still out of reach?

Comment: Sure, $x^2+x+4$ is always even.   It is widely believed (but nobody has any idea how to prove) that any polynomial with integer coefficients (and positive leading ceofficient) takes infinitely many prime values unless it either factors or unless there is a single prime that divides every value.  See the [Bunyakovsky Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).

Comment: What do you mean with common factor? Of the coefficients? These need not even be integers: An integer-*valued* quadratic could also be $\frac12x^2+\frac 12x$

Comment: I'm referring to a quadratic polynomial having the three traits described on that Bunyakovsky Conjecture page, In other words, one where there's no good reason why it shouldn't produce primes, as far as we can tell.

Comment: Post edit, I don't know what you are asking.  As you correctly remark, the Bunyakovsky conjecture is wide open, even for quadratics.  There isn't a single known quadratic which can be shown to take infinitely many prime values.  Nor, obviously, are there any known counterexamples.

Comment: I know. I'm asking the opposite, whether there are any quadratics meeting the Bunyakovsky criteria which are not known to take any prime values. Or, whether we can prove that any such quadratic must have at least one prime, which I would think is easier than proving an infinitude of them.

Comment: I think that even this easier decision is out of reach in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further thought, I realized that the answer must be **no, we currently can't prove it**.

If we could, a proof of the infinitude of polynomial primes immediately follows, since you can always split one into arbitrarily many parts. For example, the first six values of $x^2+1$ are $\{2,5,10,17,26,37\}$. But by substituting in $3x-2,3x-1,3x$ to $x^2+1$, it can be completely split into

- $9x^2-12x+5$ yielding $\{2,17,\ldots\}$
- $9x^2-6x+2$ yielding $\{5,26,\ldots\}$
- $9x^2+1$ yielding $\{10,37,\ldots\}$

each of which is itself admissible and contains a prime. To ensure admissibility, you either have to split into $k$ pieces where $k$ is not a residue of the original polynomial, or factor out $k$ if it is a residue, but aside from that, I see no reason why this wouldn't work in general, and since I'm sure I'm not the first person to have noticed this, it means that we can't prove that an admissible quadratic must have at least one prime.